# Using registerFunction in JPA workaround

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement a HQL query in Jpa which uses an MySQL `DATE_ADD` method to increase data, as apparently Jpa doesn't seem to support native add operator for timestamp.

I read some guides which suggest a class that extends the SQLDialect, and use registerFunction to register an SQL function which can be used in a query specified by that class. However, I want to instead use this SQL function inside my Jpa class instead of separate class. Does anyone know the solution to my problem? This is my code attempt, feel me to ask me for more information.

**repository class**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Conference> findByCreatorIdentifier(String creatorIdentifier);

    @Query("SELECT c.id, FROM Customer c WHERE c.date > current_timestamp() AND c.creatorIdentifier = ?1 ORDER BY c.date")
    List<Conference> findByRecentDate(String email);

//unsuccessful SQL query
//    @Query("SELECT c.id FROM Customer c WHERE DATE_ADD(c.date, INTERVAL +8 HOUR) > current_timestamp() AND c.creatorIdentifier = ?1 ORDER BY c.date")
//    List<Customer> findByRecentDate(String email);
}
```

**Update**

The `Customer` entity class stores a Date attribute as `date`, and is stored in UTC-time - 8h. I'm trying to get the mostRecentCustomer with reference to the current system time, which is intuitively `LocalDateTime.now()`, but the query doesn't seem to work too. I'm not sure if I am allowed to change the code's database schema.

**registerFunction class**

```
    public class MySQLServerDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
        public MySQLServerDialect() {
            registerFunction("conference.DATE_ADD", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP, "DATE_ADD"));
//            registerFunction("conference.DATE_ADD", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP, "DATE_ADD"));
//            registerFunction("addhours", new VarArgsSQLFunction(TimestampType.INSTANCE, "dateadd(minute,", ",", ")"));
        }


    }
```

Comment: `DATE_ADD(c.date, INTERVAL +8 HOUR) > current_timestamp()` is equivalent to `c.date > DATE_SUB(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL +8 HOURS)`, wouldn't it be simpler to just use `c.date > :referenceDate` where you pass `LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(8L)` as the `referenceDate` parameter?

Comment: I've considered your suggestion, but I think the codebase I'm using is not compatible with the suggestion. I forgot to add that the data in my Entity class is stored as Date, and if I pass in a LocalDateTime parameter, somehow it's not working. Will update my post now. Do you have another alternative with this new information?

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing what the problem is you are facing, but I don't think that using dots in the function name is allowed. Use the following:

```
registerFunction("DATE_ADD", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP, "DATE_ADD"));
```

Now the problem with MySQL is, that it requires an interval literal which requires a special keyword. There is no way to passthrough keywords from HQL to SQL directly, so you will have to use a special function e.g. `DATE_ADD_HOURS`:

```
registerFunction("DATE_ADD_HOURS", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP, "DATE_ADD(?1, INTERVAL ?2 HOUR"));
```

and then use

```
@Query("SELECT c.id, FROM Customer c WHERE DATE_ADD_HOURS(c.date, 8) > current_timestamp() AND c.creatorIdentifier = ?1 ORDER BY c.date")
List<Conference> findByRecentDate(String email);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WHERE FUNCTION('DATE_ADD_HOURS', c.date, 8) > current_timestamp()`?

Comment: No, in HQL you invoke custom functions like this. The JPA function invocation syntax only applies when the function is unknown to Hibernate and should be passed through 1:1